# Can't render fire effect on transparent background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I am trying to render a fire effect on a transparent background for a PNG sequence (Cycles). I'd like to add it to a video in After Effects.

2 problems I'm experiencing:

- renders always on black background (Although I checked box 'Transparent' in 'Film' in Render Settings, and set to RGBA
- I got the fire effect to render (I had to switch to CPU for it to work), but it appears almost not visible, with dots around it. Do you know why it appears so dull and where the dots are coming from? (screenshots attached) I added a light in the scene to make the fire more visible although I don't even know if that's necessary for rendering fire..

Any advice and feedback would be appreciated. I'm kinda stuck here :)

PS: i'm a total Blender newbie

cheers :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please attach the .blend
Alternatively it looks like you are using the compositor, since its ticked, did you connect the alpha nodes for output in it? Some post effect nodes do not carry over alpha (f.ex. Lens Distort).

Comment: here : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4144" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4144/)

Comment: Yes your problem lies in the compositor nodes. Unfortunately i do not understand what you are trying to achieve with the setup but the RGB Mix node does not carry over alpha. Depending on what you want to achieve, connect the alpha from the render to the composite and you get an image with transparency.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. That was the problem. It's fixed now :)

Comment: Related or possible duplicates as well https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32900/how-to-properly-render-smoke-on-a-transparent-background

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46606/cycles-transparency-results-in-color-loss-when-background-is-black/46815#46815