# Render Result is different from the Composite node preview

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

When I try to open image with transparency in Image Editor window it looks exactly like it should. But when I try to show it in Render Result image using Composite node, transparent part of the image (which has 0 alpha but it's color is white) looks wrong.

[image]

You can see that it is a little bit transparent, but much less than it should be, and also there is leakage around the blue blobs:

[image]

The aplha in this region of image is zero, but it looks like that when Blender displays it, it somehow changes to about 0.9.

I ran into this problem while trying to use cryptomatte for the first time.
Is there some setting I missing, or is this a bug?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48008 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46606 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46312

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that converting alpha with Alpha Over node works. As well as saving that image in EXR format instead of PNG.

[image]